# Is there a function in R that allows you to import and transform a photo from a table in format.jpg or .png to a data frame automatically?

Tags: database, automation, jpeg, photo, scanning

Is there any way to directly import jpg or png files that show a table and can be therefore read in R as a dataframe?

I've tried different programs that transform pictures into readable documents in format .doc, even with tables, sometimes it works, but I don't know if there is any feature in R that would allow this.

If this feature exists, it would be really useful to analyze very quickly and in a general way lots of documents and get different databases, that could be latter merged into one single database that may study something specific.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/ropensci/tabulizer . Another (more accurate but also not free) option is to use Google AI and the package https://dair.info/ .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).